# why doesn'y this code work?

Tags: c, exit

This question is regarding the SPOJ tutorial problem :

*Your program is to use the brute-force approach in order to find the Answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything. More precisely... rewrite small numbers from input to output. Stop processing input after reading in the number 42. All numbers at input are integers of one or two digits.*

I want to run the program without if -else statements but the program doesn't work. Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  int i;

  while (i != 42)
  { 
    putchar(i);
    i = getchar(); 
  }

  exit(0);  
}
```

Comment: `i` was not initialized during the first itertion -- its value is *indeterminate*.

Comment: shouldn't the program detect exit statement after getting value of  i equal to  42?

Comment: 42 isn't an individual character

Comment: Actually, you are reading and writing the character with ASCII value 42.

Comment: Program runs just fine for me... '*' == 42

Comment: @Foon -- so *that* is the answer to life the universe and everything. A wildcard character -- makes sense in some weird way.

Comment: You are being asked to read one- or two-digit integer numbers. `getchar()` reads a single character, you should use `scanf()` and `printf()`. But even then, your answer will fail, since you are outputting an uninitialised variable, before the input has been read. The SPOJ question asks you to output the number input, except `42` which ends the sequence - as the sample answer shows.

Comment: For starters, `getchar()` only reads one character

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty way of getting the result that you want.

Since you want the user to enter number (which is composed of multiple characters), you will want to use `scanf()` instead of `getchar()`.

**scanf() documentation** : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
  int i = 0;

  while (i != 42)
  { 
    scanf("%d", &i);
    printf("You have entered : %d\n", i);
  }

  printf("You have successfuly entered 42!\n");
  exit(0);  
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think you should supply correct answers to online challenges, and you haven't!